# Extension method on WeakReference

Tags: extension-methods, weak-references, kotlin

I've want to create extension method which will execute method only if reference is not null:

```
fun WeakReference<T>.safe( body : T.() -> Unit) {
    this.get()?.body()
}
```

usage example:

```
mTimerView.safe({startTimer(time)}) 
// OR
mTimerView.safe { startTimer(time) }
```

instead of:

```
mTimerView.get()?.stopTimer()
```

What I'm doing wrong because I'm getting: "Unresolved reference: T" ?

Or maybe there is easier way to do that without extension method?

Comment: I think that's a usability bug. The error message is misleading

Comment: How does `mTimerView.safe(stopTimer())` compile? Shouldn't it be `mTimerView.safe { stopTimer() }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an answer:

```
fun <T> WeakReference<T>.safe( body : T.() -> Unit) {
    this.get()?.body()
}
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but consider marking your function `inline` to avoid creating a lambda on each call site.

Comment: I've tried it before but i got:

Error:(35, 20) org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call 'safe' into
override fun onStartClick() {
        mTimerView.safe { startTimer() }
        mIsTimerStarted = true
        mTimerView.safe { enableStop(mIsTimerStarted) }
    }
Cause: Method inlining safe { startTimer() }: couldn't inline method call
cause: safe